# Return model data inside model function in cakePHP

Tags: oop, cakephp, model, return

I'm a beginner in cakePHP and I'm kind of stuck about retrieving data.
I have a controller, in which I want to get a users deposit amount.
Therefore I have a user model and a deposit model.
The deposit model looks like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Deposit extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array('User');
    public $useTable = 'deposits';

    public $validate = array();

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }

    public function getDepositAmount() {
        // return a users deposit amount
    }

}
```

?>

How can I tell the model to return the amount (database field is called deposit_amount) and how does it know to which user id it belongs to? Thank you!

Comment: Have you read https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html and https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html? If not do so and do the bookmarker tutorial as well https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/bookmarks/intro.html

Comment: Always specify the exact CakePHP version you are using! This looks like 2.x

Answer (score 0):

Uses of belongsTo in CakePhp

```
class Deposit extends AppModel {
    public $useTable = 'deposits';

    public $validate = array();

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
    }

    public function getDepositAmount() {
         $this->belongsTo('User')
              ->setForeignKey('user_id');
       // your find query here

    }

}
```

> Please read doc first for better understanding [CakePhp Doc](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)